# How to revoke google account access within my android app?

Tags: android, google-signin

I am new to android and would like to know how to revoke access of someone who has signed-in to my app using GoogleSignInApi.

I want my app to ask for the user's google account id when user revokes the access within the app. Currently my app automatically signs-in once the user clicks on SignIn button, even after the user has clicked revoke access button.

I am broadcasting an intent when the user clicks on revoke or sign out button of my app. Below is the code for my **MainActivity**.

```
public class MasterActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = MasterActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private BroadcastReceiver mSignOutReceiver;
private IntentFilter mSignOutFilter;

private IntentFilter mRevokeAccessFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver mRevokeAccessReceiver;


private String mUserName;
private String mPhotoUrl;
private String mEmailId;
private static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";

private ImageView profileImageView;
private TextView profileDisplayName, profileEmailId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // [START Check for sign out broadcast.]
    mSignOutFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mSignOutFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.action_signout));
    mSignOutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Sign Out in progress.");
            Intent signinIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SigninActivity.class);
            startActivity(signinIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mSignOutReceiver, mSignOutFilter);
    // [END Check for sign out broadcast.]

    mRevokeAccessFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mRevokeAccessFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.action_revoke));
    mRevokeAccessReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Revoke access in progress.");
            Intent revokeIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SigninActivity.class);
            startActivity(revokeIntent);
            finish();
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver, mRevokeAccessFilter);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_master);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   /* FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    sp = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.user_cred_sp),MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sp.edit();

    if(!sp.contains("USER_ID")){
        //Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
        Log.d(TAG, "User id not is present.");
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SigninActivity.class));
        finish();
        return;
    } else {
        // [START Set the navigation header details]
        mUserName = sp.getString("USER_DISPLAY_NAME",ANONYMOUS);
        mPhotoUrl = sp.getString("USER_PIC_URL",null);
        mEmailId = sp.getString("USER_EMAIL","noemailid@unknown.com");
        View headerView = navigationView.inflateHeaderView(R.layout.nav_header_master);
        profileDisplayName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.UserNameProfile);
        profileDisplayName.setText(mUserName);
        profileEmailId = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.EmailIdProfile);
        profileEmailId.setText(mEmailId);
        profileImageView = (ImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.ImageViewProfile);
        if(mPhotoUrl!=null){
            Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(mPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(profileImageView);
        }
        //TODO: The orientation of views and image is not proper
        // [END Set the navigation header details]
    }
}

/*@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    this.registerReceiver(mSignOutReceiver, signOutFilter);
}*/

@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mSignOutReceiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.master, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.sign_out_menu ){
        signOutBroadCast();
        return true;
    } else if (id == R.id.revoke_menu){
        revokeAccessBroadCast();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_logout) {
        // Handle the camera action
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}

private void signOutBroadCast(){
    // 1. Clear the shared preference.
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
    // 2.Send a sign out broadcast
    Intent signOutIntent = new Intent();
    signOutIntent.setAction(getString(R.string.action_signout));
    sendBroadcast(signOutIntent);
    // 3. Start the login Activity
    /*Intent signinIntent = new Intent(this,SigninActivity.class);
    startActivity(signinIntent);
    finish();*/
}

private void revokeAccessBroadCast(){
    // 1. Clear the shared preference.
    editor.clear();
    editor.apply();
    // 2.Send a revoke intent.
    Intent revokeIntent = new Intent();
    revokeIntent.setAction(getString(R.string.action_revoke));
    sendBroadcast(revokeIntent);
    //signOutBroadCast();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: "+ connectionResult);
}
}
```

This is my code for **SignInActivity**.

```
public class SigninActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, View.OnClickListener,
GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{

private static final String TAG = SigninActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int REQ_ACCPICK = 1;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 2;

private GoogleSignInOptions mGoogleSignInOptions;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private SharedPreferences sp;
private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

private IntentFilter mSignOutFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver mSignOutReceiver;

private IntentFilter mRevokeAccessFilter;
private BroadcastReceiver mRevokeAccessReceiver;

private boolean isAccntConnected;

private SignInButton btnSignIn;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mSignOutFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mSignOutFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.action_signout));
    mSignOutReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            signOutIfConnected();
            Log.d(TAG, "Sign out complete.");
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mSignOutReceiver, mSignOutFilter);

    mRevokeAccessFilter = new IntentFilter();
    mRevokeAccessFilter.addAction(getString(R.string.action_revoke));
    mRevokeAccessReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Revoke access");
            revokeAccess();
            Log.d(TAG, "Complete access revoked.");
        }
    };
    this.registerReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver, mRevokeAccessFilter);
    // [START Sign out if connected.]
    //signOutIfConnected();
    // [END Sign out if connected.]
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signin);
    btnSignIn = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);

    btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
    // [START Configure sign in]
    // configure sign in options for google account
    mGoogleSignInOptions= new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    // [END Configure sign in]
    isAccntConnected= false;
    // [START Build Google api client]
    /*mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();*/
    // [END Build Google api client]
    btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
    btnSignIn.setScopes(mGoogleSignInOptions.getScopeArray());

    sp = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.user_cred_sp), MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sp.edit();

}

/*@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    this.registerReceiver(mSignOutReceiver, mSignOutFilter);
    this.registerReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver, mRevokeAccessFilter);
}*/

/*@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mSignOutReceiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver);
}*/
@Override
protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(mSignOutReceiver);
    this.unregisterReceiver(mRevokeAccessReceiver);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onConnectionFailed: " + connectionResult);
}

private void initGAC(){
    /*mGoogleSignInOptions= new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .setAccountName(acntName)
            .build();*/
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGoogleSignInOptions)
            //.setAccountName(acntName)
            .build();
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mGoogleApiClient!=null){
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            //  If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
            // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
            Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign in");
            GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
            // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
            // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    int id = v.getId();
    if (id == R.id.btn_sign_in) {
        signIn();
    }
}

private void signIn() {
    /*startActivityForResult(AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(
            null, null, new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE}, true, null, null, null, null
    ),REQ_ACCPICK);*/
    Log.d(TAG, "Sign in method called.");
    initGAC();
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    /*if(requestCode == REQ_ACCPICK){
        if(data!=null && data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME)!=null){
            mEmail = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
            initGAC(mEmail);
            Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
            startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
        }
    } else*/
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sign in request");
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Sign in successful. Show authenticated UI
        // Set the data in intent and send it to next activity
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Log.d(TAG, "Account Profile URL: "+acct.getPhotoUrl().toString());
        String userId = acct.getId();
        String userDisplayName = acct.getDisplayName();
        String userPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
        String userEmail = acct.getEmail();

        //Set the id in shared preferences so that it can be used to log out
        editor.putString("USER_ID", userId);
        editor.putString("USER_DISPLAY_NAME", userDisplayName);
        editor.putString("USER_PIC_URL", userPhotoUrl);
        editor.putString("USER_EMAIL", userEmail);
        editor.commit();
        //dataIntent.putExtra("USER_EMAIL",userEmail);
        Intent dataIntent = new Intent(this, MasterActivity.class);
        startActivity(dataIntent);
    }
}

private void showProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog == null) {
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    }
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

private void hideProgressDialog() {
    if (mProgressDialog != null && mProgressDialog.isShowing()) {
        mProgressDialog.hide();
    }
}

private void signOutIfConnected() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        //mEmail=null;
        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sign Out using Google Api.");
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        isAccntConnected = false;
                    }
                });
    }
}

private void revokeAccess(){
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && isAccntConnected == true) {

        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Revoke access using Google Api.");
                        signOutIfConnected();
                    }
                });
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    this.isAccntConnected = true;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

/*@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    if(!sp.contains("USER_ID_TOKEN")){
        signOut();
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}*/
}
```

I may be missing something or may be doing something wrong. Please guide me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending two days, trying to understand Android activity life cycle, I was able to figure out the solution to this problem. There were two major flaws in the code above.

1. I had not registered the callbacks in GoogleApiClient. Due to this code was not flowing inside onConnected(), onConnectionSuspended() and onConnectionFailed(). Solution is to register them as shown below:

   ```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
           .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, mGoogleSignInOptions)
           .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
           .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
           .build();
   ```
2. I had enabled auto mangement of GoogleApiClient as shown in this link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/. Though this is not a flaw, right now I am unable to use it for my benefit.

It automatically connects GoogleApiClient instance when `onStart` is called and disconnects it when `onStop` is called. So when a user logs in to my app, the app takes her to MasterActivity. Along the way, `onStop` method of SignInActivity is called. This disconnected GoogleApiClient instance (*remember automanaged* ). So the solution was to manage it myself within my code.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sign in request");
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();//CALL TO CONNECT GoogleApiClient
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}

private void signOutIfConnected() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.clearDefaultAccountAndReconnect();
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Sign Out using Google Api.");
                        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                        //CALL TO DISCONNECT GoogleApiClient
                        isAccntConnected = false;
                    }
                });
    }
}

private void revokeAccess(){
if (isAccntConnected == true) {

    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Revoke access using Google Api.");
                    //signOutIfConnected(); //REMOVED
                }
            });
    }
}
 @Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    isAccntConnected = true;
}
```

I also introduced a boolean flag isAccntConnected to ensure that call to `onConnected` method has been made before invoking `revokeAccess` method as suggested here https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect. i.e. 
**You must confirm that GoogleApiClient.onConnected has been called before you call revokeAccess.**

After these changes, my app works as it was meant to be. The code to revoke access remains the same, except that I have removed nested call to `signOutIfConnected` method inside its `onResult` method.

Hope this answer will help lots of beginners like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void signOut() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                // ...
            }
        });
}

private void revokeAccess() {
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                // ...
            }
        });
}
```

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect

Comment: I am able to sign out. I want my app to re-ask google account Id when I have signed out. Initially it asks me to enter google account id and password. After that when I revoke access,then signout and after that again try to sign-in, it goes for silentSignIn. Why is it not asking for Google account Id again?

Comment: the answer was on the same page. Added to above.

Comment: I know it is there and my code also has that code. Please read my comments above.

Comment: Check your revoke is actually being called. It could be your broadcast receiver at fault. Seems a very convoluted way to do what you want to do. As only one activity is active at any one time, it seems highly unlikely that a dynamically registered broadcast receiver is going to fire from an activity that is no longer running.  Why bother with receivers. just call the Revoke code when the button is pressed.

Comment: How else should I logout or revoke? I am using this design as the SignInActivity and MasterActivity are for different purposes. Also new activity may be added in future.