# How to revoke access from Google One Tap?

Tags: android, google-authentication, google-one-tap

I have an old app where I have implemented [sign-out](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#signOut()) and [revoke access](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#revokeAccess()) options to my users. Now I'm trying to implement [One Tap](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/android/get-saved-credentials#5_handle_sign-out), where is mentioned that if we want to sign-out we need to use [SignInClient#sign-out()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/identity/SignInClient#signOut()) method, which works fine. But how about revoking the access? I cannot see any revoke methods there.

Comment: Try this suppose you will get some help- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40058425/how-to-revoke-google-account-access-within-my-android-app

Comment: @SandeshKhutalSaheb Thanks, that is what I have also used in my older app. It's a really old answer, doesn't work with One Tap.